# What verb form do we use in "espero que yo <verb>..."?

Tags: gramática, verbos, conjugación

Which of the following conjugations of **viajar** in my sentence is correct?

> Espero que yo viajaré/viaje/viajaría a España.

I am focusing on Spanish from Spain.

Comment: Hey! Northern Spainiard here. The most natural way for me would be to say "espero viajar a España" :)

Comment: Howeeeever, i do not agree with the most voted answer! Saying "espero que yo viaje a España" also sounds right to me... Although, it slightly modifies the meaning putting emphasis on ME going there. Another example would be, "espero que yo sea el ganador". Hope it helps :)

Comment: @BrainOverflow: no native Spanish speaker will ever say "espero que yo viaje a España".

Comment: @MartinArgerami Why would a native speaker not say this, like is it Latino Spanish?

Comment: It just doesn't sound right. The same way that in English you don't say "this is the car of John" but you say "this is John's car". It's technically correct but not every correct sentence is used. If you google the exact words "espero que yo no" all you find are translation, no original Spanish texts. As for "Latino Spanish", I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Smart idea to google looking for Spanish texts! In regards to "Latino Spanish" I know that other Spanish speaking countries do things differently, use different words etc... So I was curious if in another Spanish speaking country it would be correct.

Comment: I cannot tell you with total certainty because there are several hundred million Spanish speakers covering many countries. But for whatever is worth I grew up in Argentina so my Spanish is about the farthest from that from Spain. Over a lifetime one listens to people from many countries so you get a feeling (which of course could be wrong in concrete cases) about how they talk in differentn places.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I am a native spanish speaker from spain myself :) in this context it does indeed sound odd, but who hasn't heard of "espero que estés de acuerdo" ? this is an example of ESPERO + SUBJUNTIVE which is the same grammar used in "espero que viaje a españa"

Comment: @securityauditor i can confidently say it would be perfectly correct to say "espero que viaje a españa algun día", at least in the region where i live. hope it helps!

Comment: @BrainOverflow: the problem is not the subjuntive, is the "yo". It comes from literal translation from English and it is not natural in Spanish, as far as I can tell. The other Spanish speakers who answered/commented seem to agree.

Comment: @MartinArgerami yes i agree, it does sound odd. However, the OP may be tempted to conclude that it is the grammar that is incorrect, whereas it is perfectly common in phrases like "espero que yo sea el ganador" or even "espero que yo también viaje a ESP un día". Its probably just a matter of taste... :)

Comment: As a related note, "espero que viaje a España" is totally natural when talking about other people ("A Marcos le gusta el aceite de oliva, espero que viaje a España y pruebe el de allí")

Comment: @VinkoVrsalovic good point!

Comment: In English, it's: I hope to travel to Spain. And it's not espero que. It's espero followed by an infinitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct one would be *Espero **viajar** a España*.

According to the [Diccionario panhispánico de dudas](https://www.rae.es/dpd/esperar)

> Cuando significa ‘tener esperanza [en que algo suceda] o creer que sucederá’, es transitivo y va seguido de un infinitivo o de una oración introducida por que: «Espero llegar a vieja sin arrugas» (Allende Eva [Chile 1987]); «Espero que todo te vaya bien» (Gala Invitados [Esp. 2002]).

This means that whenever the verb *esperar* means "to hope for [something to hapen] or believe that something would happen," you have to use the infinitive form.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The conditional indicative is used to talk about hypothetical situations, however because I used the word "espero" it changes everything? :-(

Comment: It also expresses a desire or hope :D. So, in this case, you are not making a hypothesis about traveling to Spain, rather you are stating a wish or hope to do so.

Comment: Espero does not introduce a hypothesis. For example, if you were to say "Podría viajar a españa si ahorro suficiente" (I could travel to Spain If I save enough), then you'd use the conditional (podría).

Comment: Attention! What you say it is true when you are talking about yourself, if you change the person you need to use " Espero que tu madre VUELVA pronto", where the verb is on its subjunctive form.

Comment: Note that your quote includes "o de una oración introducida por que", so this in itself is not enough to justify/explain your "you have to use the infinitive form".

Answer (score 4):

I guess anyone but depends on what you want to say. Actually, the literal translation is the correct one:

- I hope to travel to Spain.
- Espero viajar a España.

*'Espero que yo viajare/viaje/viajaría a España'* is incorrect in all the three options

Comment: Northern spainiard here. I do not agree with the second half of your answer. Although "espero viajar a ESP" sounds more natural to me, I would say sentences like "espero que yo viaje a ESP" or "espero que yo gane la competición" are absolutely correct :)

Answer (score 2):

At least in my (northern Spain) dialect the most natural way would be `espero + INFINITIVE`

- espero viajar a España

However, at least in my dialect, it would also be perfectly fine to use `espero + SUBJUNTIVE` and not so uncommon to be honest...

- espero que yo también viaje a España algun día
- espero que yo gane la competición
- espero que me traiga buenas noticias
- espero que estéis de acuerdo conmigo en esto ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think "espero que yo ..." sounds weird/unusual/jarring to us Spanish speakers because "yo" is also the speaker themselves, so they already know as much as possible about "yo". Same with "desear/ansiar/añorar": "deseo que yo viaje a España" ---> "deseo viajar a España". Perhaps for the same reason(s) we do not have first person imperative.

Answer (score 1):

Another opción is:

> Espero (poder) viajar a España.

Here, **poder** is used to emphasize the posibility that it may not happen.